# Ollydbg enable application menu

Tags: ollydbg

i created a simple programme from visual basic 6 , added 2 submenu disabled them so they are greyed out.

now in olly am trying to find and enable them by bypassing the code.

i found the text but cannot get to enable it all i se is the acii code.

```
  004015C0      00                                    DB 00
004015C1      00                                    DB 00
004015C2      00                                    DB 00
004015C3      00                                    DB 00
004015C4      B8164000                              DD Project1.004016B8
004015C8      C0                                    DB C0
004015C9      7A                                    DB 7A                                    ;  CHAR 'z'
004015CA      45                                    DB 45                                    ;  CHAR 'E'
004015CB      06                                    DB 06
004015CC      DC144000                              DD Project1.004014DC                     ;  ASCII "openmeee"
004015D0      03                                    DB 03
004015D1      00                                    DB 00
004015D2      03004000                              DD Project1.00400003
004015D6      01                                    DB 01
004015D7      00                                    DB 00
004015D8      3C                                    DB 3C                                    ;  CHAR '<'
004015D9      00                                    DB 00
004015DA      00                                    DB 00
004015DB      00                                    DB 00
004015DC      CC                                    INT3
004015DD      14                                    DB 14
004015DE      40                                    DB 40                                    ;  CHAR '@'
004015DF      00                                    DB 00
004015E0      01                                    DB 01
004015E1      00                                    DB 00
004015E2      03                                    DB 03
004015E3      00                                    DB 00
004015E4      00                                    DB 00
004015E5      0000                                  ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
004015E7      00                                    DB 00
004015E8      00                                    DB 00
004015E9      00                                    DB 00
004015EA      00                                    DB 00
004015EB      00                                    DB 00
004015EC      D4164000                              DD Project1.004016D4
004015F0      C0                                    DB C0
```

as you can se ASCII "openmeee" is one of the sub menu and how do i enable that since i do not se jump or push